# Firebase Storage all saved photos rotation

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, image-rotation

I saved thousands photos horizontal rotation in Firebase Storage. 
How can I rotate all photos in Firebase Storage?
I tried for 7 days but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Do you have any examples of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sorry man i haven't any example. I mean I've searching solution for 7 days.

Comment: SO does really do software recommendations. You will have greater success if you some code of what you have tried. Then describe the error message or any other problems you may have had.

Comment: But i'm not getting any errors. I just wanna rotate photos in my Firebase storage. And is it possible to just rotate 5000 photos and then save in Storage? Now I get my photos in my project then I rotate my photos through CSS3. But this is very complex.

Comment: The question is a bit vague; are you asking how to rotate those images on the server or asking how to write the code to rotate the images on your device? If you're asking about the server, that's not something that Firebase Database/Storage offers as there really isn't any server-side logic to do that. However, that task could be pretty easily done on your device via code; download image, rotate, upload result etc. Can you clarify your question?